# How to convert ImageSliderViewController to Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I found a nice slider which uses `UICollectionView` to make slider image. Here's the link to GitHub: [ImageSliderViewController](https://github.com/frederik-jacques/TNImageSliderViewController).

But the problem is that it's written in Swift 1 and I'm using Swift 2.
 I installed it through pod but it shows up lot's of errors.
Is there any way to use it in Swift 2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Which **`Xcode`** are you using? When you open **Swift 1** project into Xcode, it'll ask for conversion. Have you tried that?

Following are the changes I found, after these changes its working as expected, no errors:

***Swift 1 -> Swift 2***

```
     1. collectionView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) 
     -> collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

     2. let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[collectionView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView]) 
     -> let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[collectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView])

     3. let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[collectionView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView]) 
     -> let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[collectionView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["collectionView":collectionView])

     4. pageControl.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) 
     -> pageControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     5.   required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
     ->   required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {  super.init(coder: aDecoder) //courtesy @DanielT.
     6. println -> print //in testExample
```

Comment: You missed one... `init(coder:)` should now be `init?(coder:)`

Comment: @DanielT. Yes, right (up vote for you). One more in example println -> print ;)

Comment: Also @sali... I think you should copy the classes into your project instead of importing them with cocoapods. It's bad form to modify a cocoapod file in situ.